# Where to ask: Etiquette on GitHub / Open Source Development: Should I help with the triage of issues?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, github

I often wander in the issues of a big Open Source project on GitHub.

I feel that I now know enough to spot some old issues that can be closed.
I'm tempted to do so but I wonder if it's polite (helps with triage) or not (noise on already-busy core devs).

Where to ask if it is OK?

Comment: For posterity: I asked here: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9050/github-etiquette-is-it-polite-to-help-for-issue-triage

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a [dedicated Stack Exchange site](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) for Open Source. According to their [Help Center](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions about

> how communities collaborate together to produce, distribute, market and sometimes monetize these projects

are on-topic, and I think your question might fit under this umbrella.